# Smarty: dynamic colspan

Tags: html, html-table, smarty

I have a smarty template where I want to make a dynamic colspan (one column colspawned through the full foreach. For example if foreach has only one element it's just one cell, but if it has 100 element it's a colspan through the 100 element)

My code so far, but it's not dynamic yet:

```
<table>
{foreach $myvar as $myvar}
  <tr>
   <td>{$myvar.text}</td>
   <td{if $myvar.isTrue == 1} style="background-color: green;"
 {/if}>
   {if $myvar.isSelected}<i class="fa fa-user"></i>{/if}
   </td>
   <td colspan=@count($myvar)>{$myvar.colname}</td>
  </tr>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```

How to be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Smarty to count array's length you would use

```
{$myArray|@count}
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
<table>
{foreach $myArray as $myVar}
  <tr>
   <td>
      {$myVar.text}
   </td>
   <td
      {if $myVar.isTrue == 1} style="background-color: green;"{/if}>
      {if $myVar.isSelected}<i class="fa fa-user"></i>{/if}
   </td>
   <td colspan="{$myArray|@count}">
      {$myVar.colname}
   </td>
  </tr>
 {/foreach}
</table>
```